# How to load remote data using Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hello guys I just want to ask how can I load data from my mysql table using a Kendo Ui grid.
I am using CodeIgniter as well. But I don't know how to integrate it with my code. Here's my sample code.

In my controller I have something like this. For testing i put my database query in a model which is not correct.

```
CONTROLLER

public function displayListItem(){
        $sqlSelectAll = "select * from items";
        $resultSelectAll = $this->db->query($sqlSelectAll);
        echo json_encode($resultSelectAll->row_array());
}

JAVASCRIPT PART

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: "<?php echo site_url('item_controller/displayListItem'); ?>"
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        itemid: { type: "number" },
                        itemcode: { type: "string" },
                        itemname: { type: "string" },
                        itemdesc: { type: "string" },
                        itembrand: { type: "string" },
                        itemunit: { type: "number" },
                        salescatname: { type: "string" },
                        entrydate: { type: "date" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
        height: 430,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [{
                field:"itemid",
                filterable: false
            },
            "itemcode",
            {
                field: "itemname",
                title: "Item Name",
                width: 120,
            }, {
                field: "itemdesc",
                title: "Description",
                width: 260
            }, {
                field: "itembrand",
                title: "Brand",
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "itemunit",
                title: "Unit",
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "salescatname",
                title: "Category",
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "entrydate",
                title: "Entry Date",
                width: 150
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

TO ACCESS THE TABLE

```
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Here's my table structure:

```
mysql> desc items;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| itemid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| itemcode     | varchar(100)     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| itemname     | varchar(500)     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| itemdesc     | varchar(512)     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| itembrand    | varchar(128)     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| itemunit     | varchar(45)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| salescatid   | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| salescatname | varchar(128)     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| entrydate    | timestamp        | YES  | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

I have no output with my table. I don't know where's my error. Please help me guys. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console (firebug ) ?

Comment: No there are no errors. I have an empty table only. I can't get my table values from my database.

Comment: Can you see the server request in the firebug ?

Comment: I am using Chrome. How can I check the server request? When i tried to print the json format. It list all my products. I just don't know how to call the values.

Comment: press F12 and go to network tab..

Comment: Ok and then? What's next? Is it the XHR tab?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37072/discussion-between-rochelle-canale-and-jayantha)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

call controller, use var object to store content.

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", "<?php echo site_url('item_controller/displayListItem'); ?>", false);
xhReq.send(null);
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);
```

use var object to bind datasource

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: jsonObject,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        itemid: { type: "number" },
                        itemcode: { type: "string" },
                        itemname: { type: "string" },
                        itemdesc: { type: "string" },
                        itembrand: { type: "string" },
                        itemunit: { type: "number" },
                        salescatname: { type: "string" },
                        entrydate: { type: "date" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
        height: 430,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [{
                field:"itemid",
                filterable: false
            },
            "itemcode",
            {
                field: "itemname",
                title: "Item Name",
                width: 120,
            }, {
                field: "itemdesc",
                title: "Description",
                width: 260
            }, {
                field: "itembrand",
                title: "Brand",
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "itemunit",
                title: "Unit",
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "salescatname",
                title: "Category",
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "entrydate",
                title: "Entry Date",
                width: 150
            }
        ]
    });
```

i hope this may help you:)

Answer (score 0):

In your php file request:

```
$limit = $this->input->get('sizePage');
$page = $this->input->get('page');

$data['total'] = $this->items_model->total_rows;
$data['data'] = $this->items_model->paginate($limit, $offset)->result();

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($data);
```

I was getting response from server but rows don't appears into the grid. With: header('Content-Type: application/json');, was resolved.